# Can you sell found weapons in Breath of the Wild?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I noticed that I could sell armour to some vendors, but I was pretty sure that not all people will accept clothes and I was wondering if there are any vendors that will buy weapons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this source](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75098385), it is not possible to sell weapons:

> Nope. Weapons in the game looks likes a completely different kind of
>   item. There's abundance, but you can't trade, repair (usually) or buy
>   them. They're spoils.

The exception appears to be armor only.

[Additional GameFAQs source](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75081357) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/5xg8xf/sell_weapons_weapons_vendors/).

Answer (score 2):

The NPC who gives you the side quest to get a piece of Royal Guard's equipment will also trade one gem for each piece of Royal Guard's gear you bring her. There's no way to sell regular weapons, though.